# Turn off MacVim's expanding-window effect in Yosemite

Tags: macos, vim, osx-yosemite

I just upgraded an old (2011) MacBook Air from Snow Leopard to Yosemite.  My old MacVim didn't work, and the most recent precompiled version at SourceForge didn't work, so I compiled it myself, with no `configure` additions.

I noticed that now when I open a gvim window, I see it expand from a central point, spreading out until it reaches its appropriate size.  Not all windows do that; for example, when I open a new Terminal window, it just appears without any expanding effect.  (I have "genie effect turned off in the Dock, by the way.)

Is the expanding window effect a feature in vim that I can turn off--perhaps with a compile-time option?

Or is the expanding window effect just a consequence of Yosemite's general slowness on this machine?  Maybe MacVim always did this, but I didn't notice in SnowLeopard, because it happened too quickly.  Maybe my Yosemite Terminal windows are doing this too, but the window-creation code in Terminal is more optimized than MacVim's (which wouldn't be surprising given that Terminal, unlike Vim, has to support only a single OS).

(I'd be happy to migrate this to AskDifferent.SE if that's appropriate.  Doesn't seem like the best place for Vim questions, though.  This is a programming question if it's about how vim is coded and how to compile it, but I'm not sure yet what kind of answer the question needs.)

Comment: MacVim on SourceForge? The latest builds are [here](https://github.com/macvim-dev/macvim/releases) and snapshot 77 works perfectly.

Comment: Good to know, @romainl.  Thanks.  [vim.org](http://www.vim.org/download.php#mac) gives a link to SourceForge, and it wasn't clear to me that there were binaries available on macvim.dev.  Now I know.  Happy to compile it myself, though.